# uses-sdk tag crashes live wallpaper

Tags: android, versioning, android-manifest, wallpaper

I made a little live wallpaper. I wanted to upload it to the market and got the info that I need to specify the api level. But when I set

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

in the Manifest right after closing the  tag, the wallpaper just crashes on loading. I did not change anything else between the two compiles and it runs fine without the tag. The error occurs somewhere deep in the opengl thread running the wallpaper, so the exception message is not really helpful. At least I don't know what could possibly crash there.

```
W/dalvikvm( 3838): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40201560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3838): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
E/AndroidRuntime( 3838): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must use a native order direct Buffer
E/AndroidRuntime( 3838):    at com.google.android.gles_jni.GLImpl.glVertexPointerBounds(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3838):    at com.google.android.gles_jni.GLImpl.glVertexPointer(GLImpl.java:1121)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3838):    at com.mblaster.LaserShowLWP.MyRenderer.drawLaserRays(MyRenderer.java:406)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3838):    at com.mblaster.LaserShowLWP.MyRenderer.onDrawFrame(MyRenderer.java:109)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3838):    at net.rbgrn.android.glwallpaperservice.GLThread.guardedRun(GLWallpaperService.java:675)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3838):    at net.rbgrn.android.glwallpaperservice.GLThread.run(GLWallpaperService.java:540)
I/installd(  134): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.mblaster.LaserShowLWP-1.apk@classes.dex
```

If you want to read the code of the GLThread, it's here: https://github.com/markfguerra/GLWallpaperService/blob/master/GLWallpaperService/src/net/rbgrn/android/glwallpaperservice/GLWallpaperService.java

I hope someone can help me with this.

mblaster

Answer (score 2):

OK, as nobody answered and I figured it out myself, here is the answer:

OpenGL seems to have different specifications regarding buffers on different sdk versions. It is strange that the tag actually affects it, as the code was compiled against the api version 7 anyway.

So basically all my opengl buffers, that previously where defined by:

```
FloatBuffer.wrap(float[]);
```

now have to be defined as native order direct buffers and filled via:

```
BufferName.put(float[]);
```